# Unable to distribute iOS app from VS 2019 v 16.9.2

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

The issue:
The app builds and archives successfully but will not distribute. Errors listed below. The issues started after updating to 16.9.2. Everything was working prior to the update.

Things I have already tried:

- Cleaned Solution, deleted bin and obj folders on both Mac and PC, Rebooted PC and Mac, Rebuild, Build
- Cleared all Provisioning Profiles and Certificates recreated and reinstalled on both Mac and PC
- Toggled Manual to Automatic Previsioning Build and Repeat
- Ensured the app is targeting the latest SDK and is set to release mode
- Ensured the app id matches the profile

Errors:

```
Could not create ipa file for distribution of the archive 'AppName'
/usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1

/usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1

Failed to codesign 'Path/obj/iPhone/Release/archives/ProjectName 3-21-21 10.27 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/ProjectName.app//**/*.dylib':/Users/xamarin/Libray/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ProjectName/GUIDc/C:/Path/obj/iPhone/Release/archives/ProjectName. 3-21-21 10.27 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/ProjectName.app//**/*.dylib: No such file or directory

Failed to codesign 'Path/obj/iPhone/Release/archives/ProjectName 3-21-21 10.27 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/ProjectName.app//**/*.metalib':/Users/xamarin/Libray/Caches/Xamarin/mtbs/builds/ProjectName/GUIDc/C:/Path/obj/iPhone/Release/archives/ProjectName. 3-21-21 10.27 AM.xcarchive/Products/Applications/ProjectName.app//**/*.metalib: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Hi, you best option is to report the problem to Microsoft directly from Visual Studio.

Comment: It can be some of your certificates or profiles are invalid (expired).